# I'm sending a function as a parameter, but it throws an error

Tags: javascript, callback, setinterval

Could anybody tell me why it says that myFunc is not a function?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

function useStateAsync (value, isProp = false) {
  const ref = useRef(value);
  const [, forceRender] = useState(false);

  function updateState (newState) {
      if (!Object.is(ref.current, newState)) {
          ref.current = newState;
          forceRender(s => !s);
      }
  }

  if (isProp) {
      ref.current = value;
      return ref;
  }

  return [ref, updateState];
}

function genInterval(myFunc) {
  var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    myFunc()}, 1000) // ---------- IT THROWS THE ERROR ------------------
                     // I'm guessing that it knows myFunc due to closures
  return intervalId
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useStateAsync(0);
  const [intervalid, setIntervalId] = useState(0)

  function theFunc() {
    setCount(count.current++)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIntervalId(genInterval(theFunc))
        }}
      >
        Start interval
      </button>     
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clearInterval(intervalid)
        }}
      >
        Stop interval
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(count.current)
        }}
      >
        Console log
      </button>
      <p>The counter is now {count.current}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In ordinary HTML, `onclick` attributes are executed in the global scope, so they can't access local variables. If react.js provides a way around that, you're not using that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the

```
setIntervalId(genInterval(theFunc))
```

with

```
setIntervalId(genInterval(() => theFunc()))
```